# Python. Не передавать системное сообщение окну от событий мыши

Tags: python, winapi

Есть чужое окно, в которое я отправляю системное сообщение (`SendMassege`) с кликами и перемещениями по экрану. Так вот, когда я навожу мышкой по этому окну, то получается, что мои системные сообщения переплетаются с теми сообщениями которые отправляются от мыши.

Так вот, есть ли такой способ игнорировать системные сообщения отправляемые мышью для конкретного окна? Пробовал команду `EnableWindow`, она как бы блокирует окно и клики от мыши не передаются, а вот перемещения все равно отправляются мониторил прогой SPY++ передается команда SETCURSOR.

Читал что на помощь могут прийти хуки мыши, но как я понимаю с помощью хуков можно отследить команду до того как она была выполнена и выполнить свой код, но потом же все равно окну передастся команда SETCURSOR.

```
import win32gui
hwnd=win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Калькулятор")
win32gui.EnableWindow(hwnd,False)
```